# Run code after a background process - parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, background-process

I have a findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method in my viewController. Now i want to execute code, but just until this background method is finished. How can i do that?

I'm using the swift programming lanuage.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty well covered in the documentation and guide on parse.com. But maybe you have a more specific question/scenario?

[Guide to queries on parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries)

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        println(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

Edit: specific version for PFUser to array of usernames

```
var usernames: [String]?
func loadUsernames () {

    if let query = PFUser.query() {
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil { // No error - should be good to go

                self.userNames = (objects as! [PFUser]).map({$0.username!})

                // Call/run any code you like here - remember 'self' keyword
                // It will not run until userNames is populated
                self.callSomeMethod()

            } else { // Error - do something clever

            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadUsernames()
}
```

Comment: I want to execute another method until the backgound process ended... A query appends strimgs to an array. Then i want to execute another method but only until all strings are appended! Do you know what i mean?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a specific example. Note that it will only work as is, if you are using the native PFUser objects.

I am still not sure whether or not you want to have some other loop running while the query executes, and then stop when the usernames are ready? However the comment you added below, suggests that you are calling some code in a for loop, that shouldn't be... But let me know if you are still unsure about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code that could help you. It is not clear how you would restrict the code (PRE-BACKGROUND CODE) to run only while the background processing has completed. You may want to insert some code in the notification response function either to confirm that that PRE-BACKGROUND CODE is completed or to terminate it.

```
//  ParseTestViewController.swift

import UIKit
import Foundation
import Parse

class ParseTestViewController: UIViewController {
var userData = [String]()

func codeToExecuteBeforeStringsAreAppended() {
}
func codeToExecuteAfterStringsAreAppended() {
    // can use the array 'userData'
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "notificationResponse:",
        name: "recordsLoaded",
        object: nil
    )

    self.getUserdataForUsername("MyName")
    /* ==========================
    Insert code tto be executed immediately after making the call that must not use the data returned by Parse. The function returns right away and the background may not have completed.
    */
    codeToExecuteBeforeStringsAreAppended()
}
func getUserdataForUsername (queryUserName: String) {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"UserData")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: queryUserName)
    let notification = NSNotification(name: "userDataRetrieved", object: self)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                if let username = object["username"] as? String {
                    self.userData.append (username)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)

    }
}

func notificationResponse (notification: NSNotification) {


    // this is executed after the background processing is done
    // Insert the code that uses the data retrieved from Parse
        codeToExecuteAfterStringsAreAppended()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
}
```

Comment: See my comment at the first answer :)

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. But I have modified the code to add appending an array.

Comment: I habe a PFQuery that loads all my usernames to an array called usernames! Then i want to execute a method, but only when ALL usernames are already appended to that array! The problem is, when i write the code of that methos within the for loop, it executes everytime it appends one username. But i only want to execute it after the last username it appends. So where have i to put the code? @Syed Tariq

Comment: If you implement a notification scheme as I described, the processing of the completed array should be in the notification response function. If you paste your code I will try to be more specific.