# Parse Image -> UITableViewCell Not Displaying (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm struggling to get an image stored in Parse to display in my `UITableViewCell`. The cell is being populated from other data stored in the Parse object (name, etc) - just the image isn't displaying correctly.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    if let client: PFObject = self.clientList[indexPath.row] as? PFObject {
      let forename: String = client["forename"] as! String
      let surname: String = client["surname"] as! String
      let fullname: String = forename + " " + surname
      cell.textLabel?.text = fullname

      cell.detailTextLabel?.text = client.objectId

      let userImageFile = client["image"] as? PFFile
      if let imageFile = userImageFile {
        println(imageFile)
        imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          if error == nil {
            if let imageData = imageData {
              self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
            }
          }
        })
    // THIS DOESN'T DISPLAY AN IMAGE WHEN RUN
        cell.imageView?.image = image
      } else {

    // THIS IS A LOCAL IMAGE DISPLAYED IF THE PARSE OBJECT DOESN'T CONTAIN AN IMAGE FILE. THIS DOES DISPLAY CORRECTLY WHEN CALLED.
        let image = UIImage(named: "userMale")
        cell.imageView?.image = image
        println("Local Image")
      }
    }

    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 40
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you tried println(self.image) after the statement - self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)! or right before you try to set the image into the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Your background retrieval is not complete when you plug it in as shown 'cell.imageView?.image = image'. You need to use a post a notification and after the background is done and then set the cell after you receive the notification. If you do a println on the image just before you assigne it to the cell you will find that it shows a size of 0 by 0. An example of notification is in my example code in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248787/run-code-after-a-background-process-parse-com/31250590#31250590)

Comment: I've tried adding a notification (similar to the link provided), but I can't seem to find the right place to trigger the notification. Currently it still gets signalled before the query is complete...

Comment: In the example the rigger is show with the post notification method. If you update the code inyour question I can take a look.