# Parse get data with block not assigning value to variable in scope

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview

Having issues to assign `uiImageFile = image!`. If It try to assign self.myImage = image! where myImage is a global variable it works.

Is it something possible to be done?

The code is retrieving images ok, also the cell will take an image if pointed directly. Just this bridge that is not working. And it only do not work for the image.

Also the following test line `println("TESTSTRING\(indexPath.row)")` just above the `return` is being able to get and print value from `testString = "\(indexPath.row)"` that is inside `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`.

Sorry about the question title. Not sure how to resume the issue in a single sentence.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HobbieFeedTableViewCell
        let object: PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        var myText = object.objectForKey("postText") as? String

        let userImageFile = object.objectForKey("postImage") as? PFFile
        var uiImageFile = UIImage()
        var testString = String()

        println(userImageFile, indexPath.row)

        if userImageFile != nil {
            userImageFile?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    if let myImageData = imageData {
                        let image = UIImage(data:myImageData)
                        self.myImage = image!
                        uiImageFile = image!
                        testString = "\(indexPath.row)"
                    }
                }
                }, progressBlock: { (percent: Int32) -> Void in
            })
        }

        cell.cellTitle.text = myText
        cell.cellImage.image = uiImageFile
//                cell.cellImage.image = myImage

        println("TESTSTRING\(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `cell.cellImage` inside the block (just as a test - you should in theory check to see the cell hasn't been reused before changing its image)? It seems like it's setting the `uiImageFile` variable as the `cellImage` before your data has loaded

Comment: it works inside the block. but the issue I found was when there is no image  (image is nil) it ends printing an image anyway. while I have an `if userImageFile != nil {` asking not to run that bit of code, it ends running it anyway.

Comment: but you explicitly set `uiImageFile` to not be nil before the block - you set it to be a new instance of `UIImage`, meaning that the if statement is always true

Answer (score 0):

> cell.cellImage.image = uiImageFile

gets executed before uiImageFile has been retrieved. This is because the

> getDataInBackgroundWithBlock
>   returns right away before the retrieval is done.

You can fix it by: (1) Retrieve all images into a local array in the viewDidLoad function (2) Use push notification on completion on retrieval to trigger a tableview.reload

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248787/run-code-after-a-background-process-parse-com/31250590#31250590